# how to deduce the name of product from sku when creating a product magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, sku, name

I have disabled the auto generated SKU so SKU is independent from name but in advance I want a new functionality when adding the sku 10014100 for example i will do a request in some table to recuperate the 1 that mean family1 and the 00 that mean business name and 14 the code of thickness and 100 the code of custom attribute so finally i will set the name as below :

family1 businessname thickness custom attribute value before saving the product so how to generate the name of product from sku after doing some request in DB what should i override  to  achieve that and thanks in advance

Comment: did you manage to save required data in tables ?

Comment: Have you try observer for this?

Comment: No i did not try observer because i want to set the name before saving from the value of sku